# jquery-mobile: Slider max value change properly

Tags: jquery-mobile

Im trying to change slider max value on change event like this.

```
$("#slider-1").slider( "option", "max", $("#slider-0").val() );
```

In console i see that it changes, but it does not affect the sliders behavior like id hope it would. I have tried using the .slider("refresh") method but it does not help.

Is there any trick to update the slider so it uses the newly assigned max value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/DTKDh/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $("#slider-1").attr("max", 200).slider('refresh');       
});
```

Comment: Oh thank you so much. Wish i could upvote your answer but i dont have enough reputation for that!